# Gulp: Exclude src root folder when outputting to dest folder

Tags: javascript, configuration, config, gulp

Given the following gulpfile, I would expect the contents of the `dist` folder to be the contents of `src/js/`. Instead, the contents of `dist` is `src/js/*`.

```
var del = require('del');
var gulp = require('gulp');
var jshint = require('gulp-jshint');
var livereload = require('gulp-livereload');
var notify = require('gulp-notify');
var sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps');
var transpile  = require('gulp-es6-module-transpiler');

gulp.task('build', function() {
    return gulp.src('src/js/**/*.js')
        .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
        .pipe(transpile({
            formatter: 'bundle'
        }))
        .pipe(sourcemaps.write('./'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'))
        .pipe(notify({ message: 'Build task complete.' })); });
```

How do I exclude the `src` root directory from the `dist` output directory, such that the result would be `dist/js/**/*.js`

Comment: After hacking on this issue for a while, I discovered that the transpiler is to blame. Removing it remedies the problem.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that it's to do with relative paths (compared to where you run gulp from). Try changing the dest to a relative path:

```
gulp.task('build', function() {
return gulp.src('./src/js/**/*.js')
    .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
    .pipe(transpile({
        formatter: 'bundle'
    }))
    .pipe(sourcemaps.write('./'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./dist/js/'))
    .pipe(notify({ message: 'Build task complete.' })); });
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I've added a comment to my question.